# Inserting the previous row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following table:

```
DECLARE @TempTable TABLE
(
    ID int,
    Lastname nvarchar(50),
    Firstname nvarchar(50),
    Age int
)

insert into @TempTable (ID, Lastname, Firstname, Age)
VALUES(1, 'Smith', NULL, NULL),
    (2, NULL, 'Will', 40),
    (3, NULL, 'Jaden', 20),
    (4, 'Matt', NULL, NULL),
    (5, NULL, 'Damon', 39)
```

[image]

I want to change the table using '**update**' as follows:

[image]

I know about the functions 'lag' and 'lead'. But as I understand they can not be used in **UPDATE** expressions

Comment: May we ask why you have such fragmented data?  Without a primary/group column to associated all records together, the query you are asking for could be a lot or work.

Comment: is this data already in a table? it looks like you need to fix what's putting it there like that, not updating it afterwards, unless that's what you're looking to do in a one off job

Comment: *"I know about the functions 'lag' and 'lead'. But as I understand they can not be used in UPDATE expressions"* This isn't quite true, you can, just not in the `UPDATE` clause itself . You could, for example,  use a CTE ([SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9e40a/1)). `LAG` and `LEAD` aren't going to help you here though, this is closer to a gaps and island issue.

Comment: Too add what the others are saying- lets say someone needs to change their last name due to marriage.  How will you incorporate that into such a data structure?

Comment: @Tibomso . . . `UPDATE` does not change the number of rows in the table.  You may be thinking of `MERGE` -- and you can use `LAG()` and `LEAD()` with `update`, but that doesn't seem immediately relevant to what you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one option using a `correlated subquery`:

```
update t 
set lastname = (select top 1 lastname 
                from @TempTable t2 
                where t2.lastname is not null and
                       t.id > t2.id 
                order by t2.lastname) 
from @TempTable t
where firstname is not null;

delete from @TempTable 
where firstname is null;

select * from @TempTable;
```

- [Online Demo](http://rextester.com/OLP65848)

Answer (score 2):

### Microsoft SQL solution

```
select id ,

(

    select Lastname from @TempTable c  where c.ID < p.id AND c.Lastname is not null group by Lastname
 order by max(id) desc OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY  

) as Lastname, 

FirstName,
Age

from @TempTable p
where Firstname is not null;
```

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/4922f/15

Example: http://rextester.com/IKG65840

Answer (score 0):

You can also get those results via a Recursive CTE

**Example:**

```
DECLARE @TempTable TABLE
(
    ID int,
    Lastname nvarchar(50),
    Firstname nvarchar(50),
    Age int
)

insert into @TempTable (ID, Lastname, Firstname, Age) values
(1, 'Smith', NULL, NULL),
(2, NULL, 'Will', 40),
(3, NULL, 'Jaden', 20),
(4, 'Matt', NULL, NULL),
(5, NULL, 'Damon', 39);

;with RCTE AS
(
  select ID, LastName, ID AS [NewID], LastName as NewLastName
  from @TempTable
  where LastName IS NULL

  union all

  select r.ID, r.LastName, t.ID, t.LastName
  from RCTE r
  join @TempTable t on t.ID = r.[NewID] - 1
  where r.NewLastName is null
)
update t
set LastName = RCTE.NewLastName
from @TempTable t
join RCTE on (RCTE.ID = t.ID and RCTE.NewLastName IS NOT NULL);

delete 
from @TempTable 
where FirstName is null;

select * 
from @TempTable 
order by ID;
```